# Background for Mac OS X app and other elements like NSButton, NSTabView

Tags: cocoa, macos

I changed the background color for my app, but other elements keep the same background color.
Looks like I missed some easy configuration, bsc for NSTabViewItems item colors is deprecated by docs, and using current theme...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't easily adjust the tint of the standard controls.  You're going to have to subclass and override the drawing code for each of the elements.

Also, may I humbly suggest that you leave it the default color?

Comment: Sorry, but i can't leave default color, bcs i have part of project at iphone with good color ;-). So i like a good customer experience to see a similar colors platform independed ;-).Yep, i'm going to subclass job. All issues now works well instead of NSTabViewItem's. they don't have rect for whole item, just for label, and i have no idea now how i can change it myself. NSTabviewItem instant from NSObject, so nothing to add there. Finally, i guess i must to change design from tabvie controller to segmented controller, but this is a hard way ;-)

Comment: +1 for suggesting the OP uses the default colour. @Alex: UI elements should only be altered if it adds something to the overall interface and "making it look like the iPhone version" is NOT a good reason. Users of each platform (iPhone / mac) will have different expectations of look and feel.

Answer (score 2):

U may use Core Animation layer in IB. Choose your object (for example button),
open the view effects inspector (⎇⌘8), set checkbox with your object, add "content filters" 
**color monochrome** and set color! That is all!